# How can i achieve this requirement by creating an custom object and creating a visual force page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, quote

Hi Can any one suggest me on this requirement .

PFA Screenshot

I need to add the next 6 quarters and the quantity by keeping the default sales price. giving an rough calculation of the total revenue .

As per my plan : I will be creating an custom object with the fields required and then calling them through VF page.[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Custom objects are helpful when you are going to preserve data to use later.

Here as i could understand you need to show results according to some fix values for a fixed time interval. So, It means that your data is not going to be increasing with respect to time. It will always for 6 quarters.

I would recommend to create a visualforce page which will do some calculation by fetching some values from existing object records and show on page in a user-friendly way.

If you think that your requirement can be enhanced in later time and some major functionality can be added on visualforce page then you can design the  visualforce apex controller to support custom object when required.

Another thing, using a well designed custom object will solve various complexity on visualforce page design.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.If possible can u help me out with some example related to this requirement.